# Characteristics of PDE system describing gas flow in duct

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fluid-dynamics, characteristics

> We consider a model describing the flow of a gas in a long tube. Solve the system by using the characteristics:
> \begin{aligned}
> p_t + vp_x + c^2\rho v_x &= 0 \\
> \rho (v_t v v_x) + p_x &= 0
> \end{aligned}
> Here, $p$, $v$ and $\rho$ are the gas pressure, axial velocity and density and $c$ is the speed of the sound in the gas, $x$ denotes the position and $t$ is the time.

**My thoughts:**
To solve this system, we shall conclude a system as :
$$ (p_t+ v_t)+ (p_x+ v_x)=0 $$
but how can I reduces the above system to a system with variable or constant coefficients I can solve,
or If I find the value of density of the gas, axial velocity, and speed of the in the gas, I may solve, but how can I find them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an obvious mistake in the problem statement, which should be
\begin{aligned}
p_t + vp_x + c^2\rho v_x &= 0 \\
\rho (v_t \,{\color{blue}+}\, v v_x) + p_x &= 0
\end{aligned}
We rewrite this as ${\bf p}_t + {\bf A}({\bf p}) {\bf p}_x = {\bf 0}$ for ${\bf p} = (p, v)^\top$, where
$$
{\bf A}({\bf p}) =
\begin{pmatrix}
v & c^2\rho \\
1/\rho & v
\end{pmatrix} \sim \begin{pmatrix}
v-c & 0 \\
0 & v+c
\end{pmatrix}
$$
has the eigenvectors $(\pm\rho c, 1)^\top$ corresponding to the eigenvalues $\lambda^\pm = v\pm c$. This gives us the Riemann invariants $w^\pm = p \mp \rho c v$, which satisfy the transport equations
$$
(w^\pm)_t + \lambda^\mp\, (w^\pm)_x  = 0
$$
to be solved by using the method of characteristics.

Comment: @ EditPiAf; I have posted a problem in pde [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3879131/condition-for-finite-number-of-solutions-for-cauchy-problem-of-first-order-p),can you please consider it, nobody has answered it yet and I am  very anxious to know about it.